# Identifying specific string along the row to identify the count

Tags: r

So say,
`x <- c("aa/bb:cc/dd", "aa/cc:cc/dd", "aa/cc:aa/ee")`
`y <- c("aa")`

now I need to count the substring "aa" along the row it should give me the count irrespective if it is present as two times.
eg: aa= 3 not 4

Comment: You could use `sum(grepl(y, x))` or `sum(grepl(y, x, fixed=TRUE))` for a bit of a speed boost in this case.

Comment: Ya its working for this but if I have to identify for multiple things like "aa", "bb" together do we have any option. Mine is in a dataframe as well.

Comment: You should spend some time learning the basics of regular expressions. It will be worth the effort. I like this site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/.